# Access Metamask flask from chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, popup, ethereum, metamask

I want to access metamask flask instead of metamask from my chrome extension.

https://github.com/MetaMask/extension-provider works fine for metamask, but not for metamask flask.

Can someone help me here?